# Migrate MSSQL 2008 database to MySQL 5.7 or 8.0

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008, mysql-5.7, migration

I am trying to migrate an old database runing in SQL Server 2008, to MySql 5.7 or 8.0
using MySql Workbench (Migration wizard).
It gave me this errors

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench
> 8.0\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 197, in thread_work
> self.func()   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\migration_schema_selection.py", line 183, in task_reveng
> self.main.plan.migrationSource.reverseEngineer()   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\migration.py",
> line 364, in reverseEngineer
> self.state.sourceCatalog = self._rev_eng_module.reverseEngineer(self.connection,
> self.selectedCatalogName, self.selectedSchemataNames,
> self.state.applicationData) SystemError: ProgrammingError("('42000',
> '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types
> nvarchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402)
> (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
> Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')"): error calling
> Python module function DbMssqlRE.reverseEngineer ERROR: Reverse
> engineer selected schemas: ProgrammingError("('42000', '[42000]
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types nvarchar
> and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402)
> (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
> Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')"): error calling
> Python module function DbMssqlRE.reverseEngineer Failed

Can anyone help me with this error, or is there another way I can migrate to MySQL?

Comment: File a bug with Workbench.  Meanwhile, figure out what is causing "The data types nvarchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator" and change a datatype somewhere.